# Project in S3 bucket doesn't connect to node server in EC2 instance

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, amazon-cloudfront

AWS newbie here. I have a web app where the Angular dist package is hosted in an S3 bucket, and the backend is being served on an EC2 instance. I've been following [this tutorial](https://codeburst.io/deploy-angular-2-node-js-website-using-aws-1ac169d6bbf), but after completion my project in the S3 bucket still does not connect to my remote node server.

What I understood from that tutorial was that by setting up a CloudFront distribution, it will connect the S3 bucket with the EC2 instance. But if I navigate to the CloudFront domain, it loads the S3 bucket contents but still does not connect to my node server.

When I run the node server locally, it connects successfully and I'm able to read and write to my remote Mongo database. This indicates that:

1) the connection to the remote MongoDB is successful, and

2) the front end (in the S3 bucket) is looking for a local node server instead of the remote one (in the EC2 bucket).

So my question is how do I make it so that my services make calls to the remote server instead?

Answer (score 1):

Firstly S3 only hosts static content. So all your Angular dist files will sit on S3. S3 does not connect to your backend. Your browser will try to make AJAX rest calls to your Node Server.

Second your backend Node server needs to expose its Rest services via an API gateway. Thats the recommended approach. It seems if your app is trying to connect locally because of config error. You need to use the API gateway link in your Angular app.

For a quick test you could expose the port in the Security Group of your EC2 and use the public IP of your EC2 to access the node app before going about setting up API gateway.

[image]